# API with tokens

Tags: php, api

I'm creating an API that will let games communicate with the user information and score submission to my server. I'm using an API script from http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/

What it doesn't talk about the api key (or tokens for that matter). But in getting the data that's sent from the game
ie: I want the users to log in from the game. He (the guys whose example I'm using in the link above), says not to use the method he used in the script in a real app to get the data.

What's the best way to get the data. Which are

key, gameid, email, password

Here's the script

```
$data = RestUtils::processRequest();

switch($data->getMethod)
{
case 'get':
    // retrieve a list of users
    break;
case 'post':
    $user = new User();
    $user->setFirstName($data->getData()->first_name);  // just for example,    this should be done cleaner
    // and so on...
    $user->save();
    break;
// etc, etc, etc...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at oAuth or perhaps Digest auth.

[http://oauth.net/](http://oauth.net)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would have the user log into the service securely and get a one time token or password (OTP).  This token can then be encrypted and passed back and forth as needed.